# YII PHP notice Undefined index: title

Tags: php, yii

I am new to YII, I am getting error on site load

```
PHP notice
Undefined index: title
PATH\TO\WEBSITE\protected\controllers\SiteController.php(35)
```

Below is the code.

```
/**
25      * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
26      * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
27      */
28     public function actionIndex()
29     {
30         // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
31         // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
32         $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
33 
34         $criteria->condition = "title LIKE :title";
35         $criteria->params[':title'] =  '%' . trim($_GET['title']) . '%';
36 
37         $criteria->addCondition("category_id LIKE :category_id");
38         if( !is_null($_GET['category_id'] ) && ( $_GET['category_id'] != "" ) ) {
39             $criteria->params[':category_id'] = (int)$_GET['category_id'];
40         } else {
41             $criteria->params[':category_id'] = '%';
42         }
43         
44         if( $_GET['hightRate'] == 1 ) {
45             $criteria->addCondition("user_id IN (SELECT id FROM `yb_user` WHERE rating >= 8)");
46         }
```

How can I fix this error and run my website in localhost?

Comment: You are Right Jocelyn, I put **error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);** in top of index.php, it worked!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, the best way is to fix the problem, not to hide it. A simple "Undefinex index" notice on top of your script could turn into a major error further down your code.

Comment: Absolutely right, but its a quick fix to keep working on local system. I gotta improve it and find the main problem and fix it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

define the array first:

```
$criteria->params = array();
```

then you can add to it

```
$criteria->params[':title'] =  '%' . trim($_GET['title']) . '%';
```

Update:

this might also be because of level of error reporting in php, try changing it to

```
if(isset( $_GET['title'] )) // check if title is available before using it
    $criteria->params[':title'] =  '%' . trim($_GET['title']) . '%';
```

Comment: Thanks @tinybyte, actually the website is running fine online, but when I tried to setup locally, created db in local and changed config/main.php for database settings and tested website is not running locally. Its running live OK, but not locally

Comment: also I defined param with empty array as you said, it still not working. Getting same error

Answer (score 0):

If this is the line 35 which is causing the error :

```
$criteria->params[':title'] =  '%' . trim($_GET['title']) . '%';
```

I believe the only option here to cause the `$_GET['title']`.

You should not rely on `$_GET` data with this confidence. Try rewrite this code like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['title'])){
        $criteria->condition = "title LIKE :title";
        $criteria->params[':title'] =  '%' . trim($_GET['title']) . '%';
}
```

***N.B. You should not do this kind of heavy operation in controller. Do db operations on model.***